# Help with .htaccess file's rewrite rule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I apologize in advance if I missed someone cover this already; I tried to see if someone had my own .htaccess dilemma:

I currently have the following website: *www.example.com*

I want to set it up like the following: *somewebsite.example.com*

And have the subdomain "somewebsite" point to a subfolder on my root. If that subdomain is not available, return them to an *error.html* in the root folder.

Example:

```
/
error.html
/img
/websites
    /somewebsite
        index.html
```

Here is my .htaccess for the root folder that I am working with:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^somewebsite\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !somewebsite/ !-d
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://somewebsite.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I'm not amazing with RegExp or .htaccess file, but what am I missing to accomplish my goal?

Comment: I'm not clear on what you mean by "point to".  Maybe you can describe what you want in terms of the actions possible with mod_rewrite.  Do you want to *rewrite* http://someweb.domain.com/foo  to  something else?  Do you want some requests (which ones?) to be *redirected* to someweb.domain.com? etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^./]+)\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1 -d
RewriteRule ^ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

This rule tests if *foobar.example.com* with an arbitrary *foobar* can be mapped to an existing directory located in the document root directory.

Comment: Thanks Gumbo for your help; let me clarify the scenario:

I want a visitor to come to a page http://chris.domain.com

where "chris" is a subfolder of a "websites" folder that resides in the server root (root -> websites -> chris).

so I am going to have in the server root, an .htaccess file that redirects that.

in the chris folder, I want an .htaccess file that I can tell it to be http://www.chris.com or http://chris.com (when I write to it in php)

Hope this helps clarify the scenario. THanks!

Comment: @Chris: Then just need to alter the path like: `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/websites/%1…`